# Using variable in select query with Node and MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js

I need to import data from a table with mysql and node.

In a select statement I have to use a variable("var_destino" ) in the list of fields.

This variable come from req.body.

Is there a way to do it?

```
router.post("/importacao", async (req, res) => {
  const var_origem = req.body.origem;
  const var_destino = req.body.destino;
  let sql = `INSERT INTO cl_preco_material (
    id_mat,
    data_valor,
    valor,
    reducao,
    plano_id,
    tabela_mat,
    cod_mat)
    SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT id_mat,
      data_valor,
      valor,
      reducao,
      var_destino, //my problem is here
      tabela_mat,
      cod_mat from cl_preco_material B where B.plano_id=?) AS tmp
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1 FROM cl_preco_material K WHERE K.cod_mat = tmp.cod_mat and K.plano_id=?
      ) LIMIT 1`;
  try {
    await pool.query(sql, [var_origem, var_destino]);
    return res.send({ message: "OK" });
  } catch (e) {
    return res
      .status(400)
      .send("Error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this:

```
await pool.query("SET @VAR_DESTINO = ?", [var_destino]);
await pool.query(sql, [var_origem]);
```

And mention @VAR_DESTINO in your bulk insert select clause

Comment: how to use "like" operator in sql in this case?